# Powershell Scope Issue in Sub-Function

Tags: powershell

I have the following Powershell script:

```
Function Get-InstalledPrograms {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][string]$computername=$env:computername,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [string]$ExportFile
  )
  Begin {
    $results = @()

    function ItemizeApps ($hive, $computer, $uninstallkey) {
      write-verbose "Opening registry uninstall root key $uninstallkey"
      $regkey=$hive.OpenSubKey($uninstallkey) 
      if ($regkey) {
        write-verbose "Getting uninstall subkeys"
        $subkeys=$regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 
        write-verbose "Itemizing $($subkeys.count) subkeys"
        foreach($key in $subkeys){
          $path=$uninstallkey+"\"+$key
          $thisSubKey=$reg.OpenSubKey($path) 
          write-verbose "Processing uninstall key $path"
          $obj = New-Object PSObject
          $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $computer
          $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UninstallKey" -Value $path
          $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
          $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))
          $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstallLocation" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("InstallLocation"))
          $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("Publisher"))
          $results += $obj
        } 
      } else {
        write-verbose "No subkeys"
      }
    }
  }
  
  Process {
    # Process HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE uninstall keys
    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computername)
    if ($reg) {
      # Process x86 uninstalls
      ItemizeApps $reg $computername "\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
      # Process x86 uninstalls
      ItemizeApps $reg $computername "\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    }
    
    # Process HKEY_USERS uninstall keys
    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users',$computername)
    if ($reg) {
      $subkeys = $reg.GetSubKeyNames()
      foreach ($key in $subkeys) {
        ItemizeApps $reg $computername "$key\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
      }
    }
  }
  
  End {
    write-verbose 'Complete'
    if ($ExportFile) {
      $results | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | select ComputerName, UninstallKey, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallLocation, Publisher | Export-Csv $ExportFile -append
    } else {
      $results
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting some weird issues with the $result += $obj.  Sometimes it will add the object (first time through?) and then sometimes I get the error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'. At D:\Scripts\Get-InstalledPrograms.ps1:26 char:11
+           $global:results += $obj
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Either way, when I come out of the function, $results is empty.  I am guessing it has something to do with the scoping of $results but I don't know how to fix this.  I have tried $global:results and $script:results and neither work.  What am I missing?

Comment: You are right about scope. The easy way is to just call your function with `.`. Then you will stay within the current calling scope. Example is `$data | . Get-InstalledPrograms`. But you could have unintended results if other variables are already defined outside of your function. I think best practice is just to return data you want outside of the function to the calling scope, e.g. `$results = $data | Get-InstalledPrograms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't add objects to an array using `+=`, because that is extremely inefficient as the entire array needs to be recreated on each addition.

The way your code is setup, and without making too many changes to it, I suggest you create a `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]` to store the different results in.

You didn't tag this question `PowerShell 2.0`, so I gather you use version 3.0 or better. As of PS 3.0, you can create PSObjects much easier using `[PsCustomObject]@{}`.

Also I noticed you open registrykeys, but never close them..

For the revised code below I deliberately used a different name for the resulting list, because you may still have `$results` as a global variable in memory.

Try

```
function Get-InstalledPrograms {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]$computername=$env:computername,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [string]$ExportFile
  )
  Begin {
    # create a List object to store PsObjects
    $softwareList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

    function ItemizeApps ($hive, $computer, $uninstallkey) {
      Write-Verbose "Opening registry uninstall root key $uninstallkey"
      $regkey = $hive.OpenSubKey($uninstallkey) 
      if ($regkey) {
        Write-Verbose "Getting uninstall subkeys"
        $subkeys = $regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 
        Write-Verbose "Itemizing $($subkeys.count) subkeys"
        foreach($key in $subkeys){
          $path = Join-Path -Path $uninstallkey -ChildPath $key
          $thisSubKey = $reg.OpenSubKey($path) 
          Write-Verbose "Processing uninstall key $path"

          # Power shell v 3.0 has the easy [PsCustomObject] type accellerator
          $softwareList.Add([PsCustomObject]@{
              ComputerName    = $computer
              UninstallKey    = $path
              DisplayName     = $thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName")
              DisplayVersion  = $thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
              InstallLocation = $thisSubKey.GetValue("InstallLocation")
              Publisher       = $thisSubKey.GetValue("Publisher")
              UninstallString = $thisSubKey.GetValue("UninstallString")
          })
          # close the opened key
          $thisSubKey.Close()
        }
        # close the opened key
        $regkey.Close()
      } else {
        Write-Verbose "No subkeys"
      }
    }
  }

  Process {
    # Process HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE uninstall keys
    $reg = [microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computername)
    if ($reg) {
      # Process x86 uninstalls
      ItemizeApps $reg $computername "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
      # Process x86 uninstalls
      ItemizeApps $reg $computername "SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
      # close the opened key
      $reg.Close()
    }

    # Process HKEY_USERS uninstall keys
    $reg = [microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users',$computername)
    if ($reg) {
      $subkeys = $reg.GetSubKeyNames()
      foreach ($key in $subkeys) {
        ItemizeApps $reg $computername "$key\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
      }
      # close the opened key
      $reg.Close()
    }
  }

  End {
    Write-Verbose 'Complete'
    if ($ExportFile) {
      # since you want to export all the properties, there is no need to insert a Select-Object here
      $softwareList | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | Export-Csv $ExportFile -Append -NoTypeInformation
    } else {
      $softwareList
    }
  }
}

Get-InstalledPrograms -Verbose
```

Comment: Theo, a very nice piece of code! However, for some reason it only lists 3 programs on my machine? Another function I have to accomplish this task shows 45 programs. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @RetiredGeek You're right, This had to do with the preceeding backslash on the registry paths like `"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"`. These backslashes don't belong there. Code is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62781745/11025476) gives good advice and provides a robust solution. I wanted to add explanation as to what caused errors and unintended results in your code.

When a function is called, it creates its own scope. Without targeting a specific variable scope or explicitly calling a function within a certain scope, you won't have access to its variables. If you want data created by a function, best practice will be to return that data to the calling scope and then store it.

If you call a function using `.`, it will run in the current scope. Variable modifications not explicitly scoped will be reflected back in the calling scope when the function returns.

When using the `global:` scope modifier, the global variable will be available in the calling and called scopes.

Using `+=` to add elements to an array is not efficient. This is because you are not actually adding a new element to an array. You are outputting the current array and the new element values and storing those results into a new array. As an array gets larger, that process uses more system resources.

Regarding your issues with `+=`, you will receive that error if `$results` is either not already an array, is a type that can't be converted into an array with the `+` operation, or a scalar that doesn't support appending with `+`. When `$results` is a type `PSCustomObject`, you cannot add another `PSCustomObject` to it to make an array.

```
# Example of storing function output in calling scope
$results = Get-InstalledPrograms

# Example Using . to call a function. $results will be updated in the calling scope
. Get-InstalledPrograms
$data | . Get-InstalledPrograms

# Example using global scope modifier
Function Get-InstalledPrograms {
    $global:results = 'I am global'
}
Get-InstalledPrograms
$global:results
I am global

# Example of problematic +=
$results = $null
$results += [pscustomobject]@{a=1}
$results += [pscustomobject]@{a=2} # This will error because $results is not yet an array

# Example of error free +=
$results = @()
$results += [pscustomobject]@{a=1}
$results += [pscustomobject]@{a=2} # Works because $results was already an array

# Example of mixing scopes and problematic +=
$results = 25 # This is global since it is in top level scope
Function Foo {
    $global:results += [pscustomobject]@{a=2}
}
Foo # Error because $results already existed as a non-array and incompatible type for the + operation in global scope
```